# Grab filename text between - and .mp3 and pipe into text file

Tags: bash, youtube-dl

I have a directory full of .mp3 files with filenames that contain a youtube link in it.

All of the youtube watch URL parts in particular  start with a - and end with a .mp3.

However, there is a problem.

Some youtube links have -'s in them, and some of the titles have -'s in them too.

I need to extract only this part of the video from the title:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=  (dQw4w9WgXcQ)

The title of the video downloaded with youtube-dl is:

Rick Astley - Never Gonna Give You Up-dQw4w9WgXcQ.mp3

The title of the video is:

Rick Astley - Never Gonna Give You Up

What I was trying to accomplish is to get all the links that I had already downloaded and put it in a text file that tells youtube-dl to not re-download them (download archive)

How would I go about doing this? (preferably with a bash sed command, but at this point i am willing to try anything.)

Comment: The Youtube id is always the same length. So just take the last 15 characters of the filename and then drop the `.mp3` from the end. Or whatever equivalent seems easier.

Comment: OHHH IT IS? that makes much sense.

Comment: Now all i need to do is program a script that takes the previous certain chars from .mp3 and pipe to text file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's easier than you think: the greedy `.*` followed by `-` will eat all the `-`s until the last one:

```
# first get the titles an ids into a tab-separated multiline string
both=`find * -name "*.mp3" | sed 's/\(.*\)-\(.*\)\.mp3/\1\t\2/'`

# then cut it into two multiline strings
titles=`echo "$both" | cut -f1`
ids=`echo "$both" | cut -f2`

# or process each title-id pair one-by-one
echo "$both" | while IFS=$'\t' read title id; do
  echo "$title"
  echo "$id"
done
```

Comment: i-- i don't understand what you mean by eat all the -'s.. ):

Comment: OH! I get it... Thanks!